# How to get the difference in dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble with writing a query to get difference between the UpdateDate and the CreationDate of 2 records if the ID is the lowets and the difference between the most recent and second most recent UpdateDate.
Here's my Query:

```
SELECT 
    a.ID, a.RequestID, b.KrStatus, b.CrDate , b.UpdateDate, 
    DATEDIFF (HOUR, b.CrDate, b.UpdateDate) AS TimeDifference,
CASE WHEN a.ID = (SELECT MAX(a.ID) FROM [dbo].[Krdocs_hist] a WHERE a.RequestID = 1)
    THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'NO'
END AS isMax,
CASE WHEN a.ID = (SELECT MIN(a.ID) FROM [dbo].[Krdocs_hist] a WHERE a.RequestID = 1)
    THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'NO'
END AS isMi
FROM [dbo].[Krdocs_hist] a, [dbo].Krdocs_Details_hist b
WHERE 
    a.RequestId = b.RequestId
    and a.ID = b.ID 
    and a.RequestId = 1
ORDER BY b.RequestID
```

Here's my current result:
[image]

What I'd like to do is get the last possible record, check to see if there was an existing one before it. If there wasn't compare the UpdateDate and CrDate (UpdateDate minus CrDate. If there was a record before this I want to do the UpdateDate minus the previous UpdateDate.

Using this query:

```
SELECT b.Id, b.RequestId, b.UpdateDate, b.KrStatus
FROM [dbo].[Krdocs_Details_hist] b
WHERE b.RequestId = 1
```

Has this result:
[image]

And using this query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM [dbo].[Krdocs_hist] a
WHERE RequestId = 1
```

Has this result:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the sample data and desired result?

Comment: What do you mean by sample data?
As for a desired result I need to get a row with:
ID: 39, RequestID: 1, KrStatus: 80, CrDate: 2017.06.09 and a colum that get's value from doing ROW 7 minus ROW 6 UpdateDate value.

Comment: Sample data means (some of) the original table data from which the results are derived. Then we can see what transformation is taking place.

Comment: I hope that the update provides enough information, tell me if you need more.

Comment: I'm confused because what you are doing with your script is NOT what you are trying to achieve, right? To simplify, for group records of lowest RequestID, you want to select the time different between: UpdateDate and CrDate if there is only one record in the group or UpdateDate of record with Max ID and UpdateDate of record with second max ID, right?

Comment: For the specific example I want to get max ID(39) minus the second max ID(37). If there was only 1 record I'd like to get that select it doing UpdateDate - CrDate. I have  no idea on how to go about doing it.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on ? If you are on SQL 2016 you could use LAG function

Comment: I'm using the 2014 version and I can't upgrade it currently.

Comment: `LAG` and `LEAD` functions are available from SQL Server 2012, so you can use them.

Comment: Turns out I'm actually using the 2008 version (SP3)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
Since [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) is available from SQL 2012, you can use like below:

```
SELECT
        ID, 
        RequestID, 
        CrDate, 
        UpdateDate, 
        KrStatus, 
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, PreviousUpdateDate, UpdateDate) as TimeDifference
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        ID, 
        RequestID, 
        CrDate, 
        UpdateDate, 
        KrStatus, 
        LAG(UpdateDate, 1, CrDate) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(ID)) AS PreviousUpdateDate 
    FROM [dbo].Krdocs_Details_hist) as tmp
```

I think you can try like this:

```
 SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(*) <= 1 THEN  DATEDIFF(HOUR, 
            (SELECT CrDate FROM [dbo].Krdocs_Details_hist),
            (SELECT UpdateDate FROM [dbo].Krdocs_Details_hist))
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, 
            (SELECT MAX(UpdateDate) FROM [dbo].Krdocs_Details_hist WHERE UpdateDate < ( SELECT MAX(UpdateDate) FROM [dbo].Krdocs_Details_hist)),
            (SELECT MAX(UpdateDate) FROM [dbo].Krdocs_Details_hist))
    END AS TimeDifference
 FROM [dbo].Krdocs_Details_hist
```

Comment: The result I get is TimeDifference 0 even though its more than 24 hours.

Comment: Msg 11305, Level 15, State 10, Line 58
The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled.
When trying to use LAG, and the update still returns a 0.

Comment: Turns out I was using the 2008 version and that's why I'm getting the error above.

Comment: How about the second script?